# Which clone brand with a red logo and an 'M' is this?

Tags: clone-brands

While in Poland, I have recently come across this Lego-compatible brand:

[image: Set]

What is the name of this clone brand, with the 'M' logo? A Google Images search did not yield any useful hints.

As far as I could figure out, the Chinese text on the box just indicates the name of the model, and that it's a building brick toy (obviously), manufactured by a company in [Shantou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shantou).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some Googling, it seems as the name is MG.

I found a page which lists it as a brand:
https://www.lazada.co.id/mg/?spm=a2o4j.pdp_revamp.0.0.705f736fGESNgD&type=brand

I don't even know what language it is, so didn't spend much time on the site, but further Googling of MG yields more similar results.

Looking at the box it says "MG936D". This seems to be the specific ID for this set, while "MG936" is the identifier for all their "Dinosaur World" sets.
They have other knock-off series where there is another three digit identifier.

I'm not a fan of knock-off products, but I like the consistency they seem to apply here.

Comment: `.id` = Indonesia.